Laravel observer
This is my observer class (Laravel 11) to create logs actions
namespace App\Observers;

use App\Models\Log as LogModel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserActionObserver
{
public function created($model)
{
    $this->logAction('created', $model);
}

public function updated($model)
{
    $this->logAction('updated', $model);
}

public function deleted($model)
{
    $this->logAction('deleted', $model);
}

private function logAction($action, $model)
{
    LogModel::create([
        'user_id' => Auth::id(),
        'action' => $action,
        'description' => $this->getDescription($action, $model),
        'model_type' => get_class($model),
        'model_id' => $model->id,
    ]);
}

private function getDescription($action, $model)
{
    return sprintf(
        'User %s %s a record in %s with ID %s',
        Auth::id(),
        $action,
        get_class($model),
        $model->id
    );
}
}

Here I have registered in AppServiceProvider:
  public function boot(): void
  {
    Paginator::useBootstrapFive();

    Car::observe(UserActionObserver::class);
    CarColor::observe(UserActionObserver::class);
  }

Now when I perform actions on Car or CarColor model its not calling observer functions, means no logs are creating

There might be many factors. Depends how you call the save\create method of Car class. Is the Car class model setup correctly ? Table name, columns etc, or Log model. Have you used "fillable" property on models ?  If yes and columns are not present  in the fillable property the data wont be saved.

I have applied all these thing, from controller I can create Log, I have tested with laravel log its actually not running the observer any function

you need to include a case of the observer not working
